# progressive engagement with devise in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to implement a functionality that would allow guests to submit booking forms and then be redirected to sign-in or subscribe in order to save it. Superprof.co.uk has the same functionality so here's what I mean:

1. As a guest (a user who isn't signed in) can click on "book a course" in what would be the "course#show" page in rails[image]
2. He is then redirected to fill the booking form (even if he isn't signed in)
   [image]
3. When he submits the form he is asked to subscribe or sign-in.[image]

Is there a way to do something similar with devise? How can I keep the booking information and save it only after the user signs in ? Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to save booking information to `session[:booking]`. Then overwrite devise controller and after sign up or sign in check if `session[:booking]` is set and if so create booking records in DB.

A more correct but also a more complicated approach would be to use guest user. You can check [guest user record railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record) for more information about that.